# multiplication of infinite series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm learning about [generalized Lindley distribution](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/46693900/s13571-011-0025-920160621-3539-oyb9hy.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1558588228&Signature=Mg4vgPoJWmh7Wz8Vm3cQA4%2FmgIM%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DA_generalized_Lindley_distribution.pdf) and currently trying to find the distribution's moment by using this integral: 
$$ K(a,b,c,\delta) = \int_{0}^\infty x^c (1+x) \left[1-{1+b+bx\over1+b}e^{-bx}\right]^{a-1} e^{-\delta x} dx $$

All constants $ a, b, c, $ and $ \delta $ are assumed to be positive. The paper then modifies the integral by using series expansion defined by: 
$$(1-z)^s = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{s}{i} (-1)^i z^i $$

Based on the series expansion, I can get: 
$$ \left[1-{1+b+bx\over1+b}e^{-bx}\right]^{a-1} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{a-1}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{(1+b)^i} \left[1+b(1+x)\right]^i e^{-ibx}$$
$$ \left[1+b(1+x)\right]^i = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{i}{j} b^j (1+x)^j $$
$$ (1+x)^{j+1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{j+1}{k} x^k $$

Then, the integral can be restated as: 
$$ K(a,b,c,\delta) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{k=0}^{j+1} \binom{a-1}{i} \binom{i}{j} \binom{j+1}{k} \frac{(-1)^i b^j \Gamma(c+k+1)}{(1+b)^i (bi+\delta)^{c+k+1}} $$

I'm trying to find the convergence of the function $ K(a,b,c,\delta) $ but I have some difficulties. First, I would like to know if the series on the function is equal with multiplications of series defined below: 
$$ K(a,b,c,\delta) = \left[\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{a-1}{i} \frac{(-1)^i}{(1+b)^i}\right] \left[\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j} b^j\right] \left[\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{k=0}^{j+1} \binom{j+1}{k} \frac{\Gamma(c+k+1)}{(bi+\delta)^{c+k+1}}\right] $$

If the series can be defined above, I'm thinking of using [Cauchy's Multiplication Theorem](http://www.iaz.uni-stuttgart.de/LstAGeoAlg/Pressland/ana1a-win11files/wk8.pdf) for series and find the convergence of every series in the function. The convergence of the first series is easily found by using ratio test that results in the absolute convergence of the series. For the second series, it can be defined as: 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j} b^j = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (1+b)^i $$

However, the series is divergent because it is a geometric series with more than one ratio value (since $ b $ is assumed to be positive). Therefore, I can't use Cauchy's Theorem to find the convergence of $ K(a,b,c,\delta) $.

For the third series, I found that it can be defined as [Hurwitz Zeta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html) that supposed to be a convergent series. So, I would like to know whether there is any alternative to test the function's convergence or whether I made any mistake or not.

I apologize for the long post and want to say thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Nice first question!

Comment: Thank you very much! :)